# Gateway Timeout при попытке оплаты через PayPal или Stripe в Woocommerce. Как устранить проблему?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Привет всем!

Получаю ошибку Gateway Timeout при попытке оплаты через PayPal или Stripe в Woocommerce. Пробовал отключать плагины - не помогло. Как можно устранить эту проблему?

[image]

`

```
### WordPress Environment ###

Home URL: https://www.qhhtofficial.com
Site URL: https://www.qhhtofficial.com
WC Version: 3.2.6
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 4.9.1
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 768 MB
WP Debug Mode: ✔
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_US

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 7.0.26
PHP Post Max Size: 256 MB
PHP Time Limit: 500
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.57.0
OpenSSL/1.0.2m

SUHOSIN Installed: –
Max Upload Size: 32 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 3.2.6
WC Database Prefix: wp_
Total Database Size: 302.74MB
Database Data Size: 208.40MB
Database Index Size: 94.34MB
wp_woocommerce_sessions: Data: 9.02MB + Index: 0.09MB
wp_woocommerce_api_keys: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_woocommerce_order_items: Data: 0.42MB + Index: 0.16MB
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Data: 3.52MB + Index: 4.02MB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_woocommerce_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_a3_exclude_email_subject: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_advanced_notifications: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_advanced_notification_triggers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_aryo_activity_log: Data: 0.33MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_bbpas: Data: 1.02MB + Index: 4.12MB
wp_booking: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_bookingdates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_bp_activity: Data: 13.50MB + Index: 2.28MB
wp_bp_activity_meta: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_bp_friends: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_bp_groups: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_bp_groups_groupmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_bp_groups_members: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB
wp_bp_messages_messages: Data: 1.48MB + Index: 0.17MB
wp_bp_messages_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_bp_messages_notices: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_bp_messages_recipients: Data: 0.18MB + Index: 0.47MB
wp_bp_notifications: Data: 0.41MB + Index: 0.97MB
wp_bp_notifications_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_bp_user_blogs: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_bp_user_blogs_blogmeta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_bp_xprofile_data: Data: 0.28MB + Index: 0.25MB
wp_bp_xprofile_fields: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.08MB
wp_bp_xprofile_groups: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_bp_xprofile_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_cjfm_custom_fields: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_cjfm_custom_fields_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_cjfm_custom_forms: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_cjfm_invitations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_cjfm_options: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_cjfm_temp_users: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_commentmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_comments: Data: 4.52MB + Index: 3.70MB
wp_cx_chat_logs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_cx_conversations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_cx_users: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_duplicator_pro_entities: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_duplicator_pro_packages: Data: 0.03MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ewwwio_images: Data: 1.31MB + Index: 0.63MB
wp_followup_coupons: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_coupon_logs: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_customers: Data: 0.07MB + Index: 0.15MB
wp_followup_customer_carts: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_followup_customer_notes: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_customer_orders: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_followup_email_coupons: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_email_excludes: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_email_logs: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_email_orders: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_followup_email_order_coupons: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_email_tracking: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_followup_history: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_order_categories: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.12MB
wp_followup_order_items: Data: 0.07MB + Index: 0.16MB
wp_followup_subscribers: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_followup_subscribers_to_lists: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_followup_subscriber_lists: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_groups_capability: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_groups_group: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_groups_group_capability: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_groups_user_capability: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_groups_user_group: Data: 0.31MB + Index: 0.22MB
wp_hook_list: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_cms_nav_cache: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_content_status: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_core_status: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_flags: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_languages: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_icl_languages_translations: Data: 0.10MB + Index: 0.11MB
wp_icl_locale_map: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_message_status: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_node: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_reminders: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_strings: Data: 0.61MB + Index: 0.42MB
wp_icl_string_positions: Data: 1.48MB + Index: 0.40MB
wp_icl_string_status: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_string_translations: Data: 0.31MB + Index: 0.13MB
wp_icl_translate: Data: 0.24MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_icl_translate_job: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_icl_translations: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_icl_translation_status: Data: 0.10MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_layerslider: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_links: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_login_redirects: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_mainwp_stream: Data: 3.81MB + Index: 2.11MB
wp_mainwp_stream_context: Data: 1.29MB + Index: 0.66MB
wp_mainwp_stream_meta: Data: 9.67MB + Index: 3.85MB
wp_monalisa: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_mona_reactions: Data: 0.30MB + Index: 0.08MB
wp_options: Data: 7.09MB + Index: 0.20MB
wp_pmxe_exports: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxe_posts: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxe_templates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxi_files: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxi_history: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxi_imports: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxi_posts: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pmxi_templates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_postmeta: Data: 28.44MB + Index: 27.45MB
wp_posts: Data: 22.39MB + Index: 3.69MB
wp_revslider_css: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_revslider_layer_animations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_revslider_navigations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_settings: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_sliders: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_revslider_slides: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_revslider_static_slides: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_rt_rtm_activity: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_rt_rtm_api: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_rt_rtm_media: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_rt_rtm_media_interaction: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_rt_rtm_media_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfadminkeywords: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfadmintasks: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_sfauthcats: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfauths: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfcache: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfdefpermissions: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfdigest: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sferrorlog: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfeventlog: Data: 0.33MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfforums: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_sfgroups: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfkeywords: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_sflinks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_sflog: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sflogmeta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfmembers: Data: 9.12MB + Index: 0.12MB
wp_sfmemberships: Data: 0.09MB + Index: 0.19MB
wp_sfmeta: Data: 0.36MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfnotices: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfoptions: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_sfpermissions: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_sfpostattachments: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfpostratings: Data: 0.32MB + Index: 0.15MB
wp_sfposts: Data: 6.02MB + Index: 0.50MB
wp_sfroles: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfspecialranks: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sftagmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB
wp_sftags: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_sftopics: Data: 0.09MB + Index: 0.09MB
wp_sftrack: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfuseractivity: Data: 0.33MB + Index: 0.44MB
wp_sfusergroups: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfwaiting: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sfwarnings: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_signups: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_simple_login_log: Data: 1.63MB + Index: 0.15MB
wp_smush_dir_images: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_termmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_terms: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_term_relationships: Data: 0.14MB + Index: 0.09MB
wp_term_taxonomy: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.06MB
wp_upme_post_features: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_usermeta: Data: 19.55MB + Index: 17.95MB
wp_users: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 0.55MB
wp_vp_id: Data: 17.55MB + Index: 14.06MB
wp_wc_deposits_payment_plans: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wc_deposits_payment_plans_schedule: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfbadleechers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfBadLeechers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfBlockedCommentLog: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfblockediplog: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfBlockedIPLog: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfblocks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfBlocks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfblocksadv: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfBlocksAdv: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfconfig: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfConfig: Data: 0.27MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfcrawlers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfCrawlers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfFileMods: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wffilemods: Data: 4.52MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfHits: Data: 2.02MB + Index: 0.20MB
wp_wfhits: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 0.36MB
wp_wfHoover: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfhoover: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfIssues: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfissues: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfknownfilelist: Data: 2.52MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfKnownFileList: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfleechers: Data: 0.17MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfLeechers: Data: 1.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wflockedout: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfLockedOut: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfLocs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wflocs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfLogins: Data: 0.17MB + Index: 0.06MB
wp_wflogins: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_wfNet404s: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfnet404s: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfNotifications: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfPendingIssues: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfreversecache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfReverseCache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfscanners: Data: 0.09MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfScanners: Data: 1.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfsnipcache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_wfSNIPCache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB
wp_wfstatus: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.09MB
wp_wfStatus: Data: 1.02MB + Index: 0.11MB
wp_wfThrottleLog: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfthrottlelog: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wfVulnScanners: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wfvulnscanners: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpfront_ure_login_redirect: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpfront_ure_options: Data: 0.03MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpml_mails: Data: 18.45MB + Index: 0.07MB
wp_wpsp_agent_settings: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpsp_attachments: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpsp_catagories: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpsp_panel_custom_menu: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpsp_ticket: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpsp_ticket_thread: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpuf_transaction: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wp_auth_session_tbl: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wp_wp_wp_hook_list: Data: 1.23MB + Index: 0.56MB
wp_wsal_metadata: Data: 0.14MB + Index: 0.06MB
wp_wsal_occurrences: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_wsal_options: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_yoast_seo_links: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_yoast_seo_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB

### Post Type Counts ###

acf-field: 9
acf-field-group: 2
achievement-type: 1
ajde_events: 55
attachment: 694
avada_faq: 2
avada_portfolio: 2
bnfw_notification: 1
bp-email: 48
custom_css: 1
easy-pricing-table: 1
forum: 35
maplist: 431
membership_plan: 2
nav_menu_item: 54
openmenu: 1
page: 84
payment_retry: 14
post: 22
postman_sent_mail: 500
product: 65
product_variation: 4
reply: 7082
revision: 9
rtmedia_album: 8
sc_event: 1
scheduled-action: 591
shop_coupon: 24
shop_order: 2804
shop_order_refund: 10
shop_subscription: 1900
shop_webhook: 2
tablepress_table: 8
testimonials-widget: 12
ticket-meta-fieldset: 2
topic: 1179
tribe_events: 55
tribe_organizer: 5
tribe_venue: 10
tribe_wooticket: 56
tshowcase: 77
uaio_user_listing: 1
uaio_user_profile: 3
wafs: 1
wp_email_images: 1
wpcf7_contact_form: 10
wpuf_forms: 2
wpuf_input: 12
wpuf_profile: 2

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (48) ###

Advanced Custom Fields PRO: by Elliot Condon – 5.6.4
bbPressCustomFields: by T3 Web Design – 1.0
bbPress Advanced Statistics: by Jake Hall – 1.5
bbPress: by The bbPress Community – 2.5.14
rtMedia for WordPress, BuddyPress and bbPress: by rtCamp – 4.4.4
BuddyPress: by The BuddyPress Community – 2.9.2
CB Change Mail Sender: by Md Abul Bashar – 1.1
Cimy User Manager: by Marco Cimmino – 1.5.0
Contact Form 7: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 4.9.2
Error Log Monitor: by Janis Elsts – 1.5.6
Event Tickets Plus: by Modern Tribe
Inc. – 4.6.1.1

Event Tickets: by Modern Tribe
Inc. – 4.6.2

The Events Calendar PRO: by Modern Tribe
Inc. – 4.4.19

EWWW Image Optimizer: by Shane Bishop – 4.0.5
GD bbPress Attachments: by Milan Petrovic – 2.5
Genesis Connect for WooCommerce: by StudioPress – 0.9.9 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
Genesis Style Trump: by Carrie Dils – 1.0.4
Google Language Translator: by Rob Myrick – 5.0.33
Groups bbPress: by itthinx – 1.0.0
Groups WooCommerce: by itthinx – 1.11.3 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
Groups: by itthinx – 2.3.0
Easy HTTPS (SSL) Redirection: by Tips and Tricks HQ – 1.7
Index Autoload: by LittleBizzy – 1.0.4
Mailgun: by Mailgun – 1.5.8.5
Mona Reactions: by Mona Media – 1.7.1
Stripe Payment Gateway for WooCommerce ( Basic ): by XAdapter – 3.0.7
Popular Posts by Webline: by Weblineindia – 1.0.4
Really Simple CAPTCHA: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 2.0.1
Simple Login Log: by Max Chirkov – 1.1.3
Testimonials Widget: by Axelerant – 3.4.2
The Events Calendar: by Modern Tribe
Inc. – 4.6.8

UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore: by UpdraftPlus.Com
DavidAnderson – 1.14.2

User Switching: by John Blackbourn – 1.3.0
Woocommerce Add Countries: by Daniele De Santis – 1.1 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
WooCommerce Advanced Free Shipping: by Jeroen Sormani – 1.1.3
WooCommerce Deposits: by Automattic – 1.3.4
WooCommerce Export Customer Email: by MH Mithu – 1.3 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
Follow-Up Emails: by WooCommerce – 4.5.2 – 4.6.3 is available
WooCommerce Stripe Gateway: by WooCommerce – 3.2.3 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
WooCommerce Product Add-ons: by WooCommerce – 2.9.0 – 2.9.1 is available – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
WooCommerce Subscriptions: by Prospress Inc. – 2.2.13 – 2.2.16 is available – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
WooCommerce: by Automattic – 3.2.6
Wordfence Security: by Wordfence – 6.3.22
WP Crontrol: by John Blackbourn & contributors – 1.6.2
WP Migrate DB: by Delicious Brains – 1.0.2
WP-Optimize: by David Anderson
Ruhani Rabin
Team Updraft – 2.1.1

WP Rocket: by WP Media – 2.10.6
WP Smush: by WPMU DEV – 2.7.6

### Settings ###

API Enabled: ✔
Force SSL: ✔
Currency: USD ($)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
subscription (subscription)
variable (variable)
variable subscription (variable-subscription)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)


### WC Pages ###

Shop base: #52418 - /shop
Cart: #52419 - /cart
Checkout: #52420 - /checkout
My account: #52421 - /my-account
Terms and conditions: ❌ Page not set

### Theme ###

Name: QHHT
Version: 2.2.4
Author URL: http://www.t3webservices.com
Child Theme: ✔
Parent Theme Name: Genesis
Parent Theme Version: 2.5.3
Parent Theme Author URL: https://www.studiopress.com/
WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Overrides: –

### subscriptions ###

WCS_DEBUG: ✔ No
Subscriptions Mode: ✔ Live
Report Cache Enabled: ✔ Yes
Cache Update Failures: ✔ 0 failure
`
```

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Может, кто и сталкивался. Только приведённая информация малоинформативна. А какие настройки PayPal? А пробовали в режиме sandbox? А включены отладочные логи PayPal? А что в них? А пробовали отключить все плагины, кроме WooCommerce и сменить тему на стандартную?

Comment: @KAGGDesign PayPal в режиме Sandbox тоже вызывает ошибку при ajax запросе, хотя в логах PayPal написано, что оплата прошла успешно и в админке ВП видно, что подписка продлена. Пробовал отключать плагины, не помогло. max_execution_time установил 500, тоже не помогло. Тему менять не пробовал еще, сервер Apache стоит.

Comment: А заказ WooCoomerce переход в статус "выполнен"? И что будет, если не подписку продлевать, а обычный тестовый товар купить (отключив плагин подписки)? Как я вижу, вы не все плагины отключили, кроме WC, потому что никакой подписки в WC нет